# Angular Bootstrap Popover Open only 1 Popover at a time and close all if clicked anywhere else

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Under the title "metrics" there is a PROGRESS bar on click of progress bar a POPOVER opens I anticipate to have only 1 popover opened at a time.
i.e for eg: if 1 popup is open already so on click of second the other opened one should close automatically. `[http://puu.sh/jjWne/053c884555.png][1]` here like both are opened at a time whereas 1 should only open.
Here is the [link](http://goo.gl/Z6wTG4)

I have to paste url as this is ajax based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem long time back,

use this script to hide popovers when you click on outside.

```
$(document).on('click','body',function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () { 
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: the popover is not on the anchor tag but on the progress bar

Comment: @user930026 its working or not, I saw popover is on div progress  with attribute of data-toggle="popover" , so thats why I applied to popover attributes, if its not working share fiddle once please

Comment: Hey Its working fine I tested in your link http://creativescripters.com/clients/work/ , just paste this script in your javascript console and check once again

Comment: added to script.js at very bottom :( sorry cannot get it to work

Comment: sorry It is not working, Just updated the answer. add this script to script.js once and check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Couldnt have done with your help.

Comment: Also on the same link can you please help me understand how to make only 1 accordion open at a time. so only 1 collapsible should be open at a time this all is pretty easy in jquery angular is kinda pain